# Cannot start Sails.JS server

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I just installed a fresh Sails.JS using `sails new sails`. I have installed all the dependencies, and the node_modules folder is available. But when I try to run the server using `sails lift`, it give me errors:

```
error:
error: Error:
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
No `sails.config.sockets.onlyAllowOrigins` or `sails.config.sockets.beforeConnect`
setting was detected.  For security reasons, one of these options must be set
when running Sails in a production environment.
For example (in config/env/production.js):

sockets: {
  onlyAllowOrigins: ["http://www.mydeployedapp.com", "http://mydeployedapp.com"]
}


-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

    at Hook.configure (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\lib\configure.js:60:13)
    at Hook.wrapper [as configure] (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3275:19)
    at A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\loadHooks.js:331:20
    at A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3083:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1003:9)
    at eachOf (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1051:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3145:5)
    at configure (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\loadHooks.js:328:17)
    at A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3853:24
    at replenish (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:946:17)
    at iterateeCallback (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:931:17)
    at A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:906:16
    at A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3858:13
    at A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:421:16
    at iteratorCallback (A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:998:13)
    at A:\Projects\sails\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:906:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

error: Could not load Sails app.
error:
error: Tips:
error:  • First, take a look at the error message above.
error:  • Make sure you've installed dependencies with `npm install`.
error:  • Check that this app was built for a compatible version of Sails.
error:  • Have a question or need help?  (http://sailsjs.com/support)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Read my question again

Comment: What happens when you ignore your present `onlyAllowOrigins` setting and do the alternate way using `beforeConnect` as `beforeConnect: function(handshake, proceed) { return proceed(undefined, true);},`

Comment: looks like u r trying to run in prod mode which requires u to specify your allowed origins. it looks like u have NODE_ENV exported as production. try to do `NODE_ENV=development sails lift`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not using sockets in your application then opens the .sailsrc file present in your project root folder and add the hooks object in it

```
{
    "generators": {
         "modules": {}
    },
    "hooks" : {
          "sockets" : false
    },
    "_generatedWith": {
           "sails": "1.0.2",
           "sails-generate": "1.15.28"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have noticed that the order in the writing the object is very vital else it will throw an error. For example, placing hooks after _generatedWith will not work

Answer (score 0):

Simple enter the 'http://localhost' in your production.js file

```
onlyAllowOrigins: [
  'https://example.com',
  'https://staging.example.com',
  **'http://localhost'**
],
```